# Selenium not printing inner text of div

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am using selenium to try to scrape data from a website (https://www.mergentarchives.com/), and I am attempting to get the innerText from this element:

```
<div class="x-paging-info" id="ext-gen200">Displaying reports 1 - 15 of 15</div>
```

This is my code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()

search_url = 'https://www.mergentarchives.com/search.php'

driver.get(search_url)
assert 'Mergent' in driver.title

company_name_input = '//*[@id="ext-comp-1009"]'
search_button = '//*[@id="ext-gen287"]'

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(company_name_input).send_keys('3com corp')
driver.find_element_by_xpath(search_button).click()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ext-gen200').text)
```

basically I am just filling out a search form, which works, and its taking me to a search results page, where the number of results is listed in a div element. When I attempt to print the text of this element, I simply get a blank space, there is nothing written and no error.

```
[Finished in 21.1s]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try putting a `print('before')` and print after your `print(driver...` statement. See what happens. If you get "before \n after" it means that `driver...` returns an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need explicit Wait :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
info = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'x-paging-info' and @id='ext-gen200']"))).get_attribute('innerHTML')
print(info)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to put a condition by verifying if search results loaded or not and once its loaded you can use below code

```
print(driver.find_element_by_id('ext-gen200').text)
```